# IBM MobileFirst 7.1.0 APNS Certificate error: Unable to process certificate

Tags: push-notification, apple-push-notifications, ibm-mobilefirst

Push Notification for Apple was tried to implement using IBM MFP 7.1.0.

Sandbox certificate `apns-certificate-sandbox.p12` in the project directory[`apps/MyApp/apns-certificate-sandbox.p12`] was added.

Below error has occurred, while the project was built.

```
FWLST1040E: iphone build failed: com.worklight.common.util.WorklightCertificateException: Certificate error: Unable to process certificate: apns-certificate-sandbox.p12
```

As per the earlier post's about the similar issue in this forum are tried. Ex: [worklight-62-encrypt-ios-pushsender-password-in-application-descriptor](http://databasefaq.com/index.php/answer/81330/worklight-worklight-security-worklight-62-encrypt-ios-pushsender-password-in-application-descriptor)

These two options are tried but still problem remains.

> 1. `<pushSender password="password"/>` in application-descriptor.xml
> 2. `<pushSender password="${passwd}"/>`in application-descriptor.xml
>    `passwd=password`in worklight.properties

A sample `helloworld` project is created & iphone environment added. As per the above drafted procedure tried and no luck with below combination.

1. IBM MFP 7.0.0.00.20150706-1910
2. IBM MFP 7.1.0.00.20151227-1725
3. IBM MFP 7.1.0.00.20160513-1006

Comment: Are you sure your certificate is valid and correctly generated? How did you generate it?

Comment: How did you create the .p12 file?  Are you 100% sure it's really a PKCS#12 file?  I don't think this is related to the problem you pointed out, because that only affected situations where the password was passed in as a variable name - you are having the problem with the password passed in as a static text string too, which leads me to the conclusion that this is a different issue entirely.  (Heh ... I was composing this at the same time Idan posted a similar quesiton...)

Comment: (https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/worklight/entry/understanding-and-setting-up-push-notifications-in-development-evnironment?lang=en) followed the same link to generate .p12 and at last generated the password. @idan

Comment: 1) Do you have multiple apns p12 files within the project ?
2) Are you sure of the password entered? Is that correct?

Comment: no vivin single apns .p12 file and password is correct @vivin

Comment: It still does not seem the certificate is correctly generated. Try to create a new one.

Comment: Try removing the environment, adding it again and doing a "build iphone/ipad environment'

Comment: @jais, did you try the above suggestion?

Comment: @idan , Hi Idan that was problem in generating the certificate,sorry:-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suspects in the comments, the problem was with the .p12 certificate. Once it has been regenerated the problem was resolved.